# ngModel not updated in ng-select component

Tags: angular, select, dropdown, angular2-forms, angular-ngselect

I have ng-select component in my code and it initializes as below in HTML.

```
<ng-select id="SelectType" placeholder="Student" [multiple]="true"
              [items]="students" groupBy="type" [selectableGroup]="false" [(ngModel)]="selectedstudents"
              [closeOnSelect]="false" bindLabel="name" (add)="onSelectFirstDropdown($event)"
              (remove)="onRemoveFirstDropdown($event.value)">
```

I have select multiple students from the dropdown and after doing some modifications in the ts file I want to remove one student in "selectedstudents" List. But when I remove the item from the list it's not updated to the ng-select and item still remain selected in the dropdown. How can I solve this issue? 
Thank you

Comment: Add more info, show your classes. Suppose ChangeDetectionStrategy is onPush...

Comment: How did you remove an item from selectedstudents? Do you get an new array or is it the same instance? If same instance, then create a new with:  this.selectedstudents = [...this.selectedstudents];

Answer (score 0):

To add/remove items dynamically at runtime from the `ngModel`, you have to create a new instance of the model object then you can add/remove items from it; otherwise, angular not detect the changes.

Create a new instance of `selectedstudents` -

`this.selectedstudents = [...this.selectedstudents];`

Remove items from `selectedstudents` -

`this.selectedstudents.pop()`